# How to link mysql query to a php process?

Tags: mysql, php, sql

I noticed I have an abnormally large amount of `mysqld` processes which have various mysql queries; I've restarted `mysqld` and all of these processes come back within 10 seconds.

I know the processes are being spawned using php; but do not know how to trace this. How does one do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question this is what I found; it depends heavily on your environment and involves the usage of `lsof` and `strace`.

You'll need to find the process ID of your request (using `lsof` or `netstat` or any other network tool in Linux). Once you've got this you'll want the parent process ID which you can get through `ps`. You will then want to strace that PPID with the following: `strace -f -tt -T -s 10000 -p <PPID> -o ~/out.strace`.

Another way to do this is more advanced and involves the usage `/proc/`. You'll also have to get the PPID of your connection using `lsof`. You will then do an `ls -la /proc/<ppid>/fd/` and grep for `socket:[*number*]`. You will then do an `lsof` on all the *number*s and then `strace` all of the pid's from those *number*s.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're running multiple database -instances- you should only have one mysqld process running.

Answer (score 0):

Run the next query from the CLI-client or from phpmyadmin or your favourite mysql-tool:

```
SELECT `USER`, 
       `HOST`, 
       `DB`, 
       `COMMAND`, 
       `TIME`, 
       `STATE`, 
       LEFT(`INFO`, 51200) AS `Info` 
   FROM `information_schema`.`PROCESSLIST`;
```

and you'll see who has locked your bases. Certainly, I'm sure that at least one index in your bases is broken and has to be rebuilt. You have to run DB analysis/reparing to fix your problem:

```
REPAIR TABLE database.table;
```